# Reviewing a First Answer with red flags leads to "Possible spam" notice shown for question

Tags: bug, status-review, review, answers, spam

There is a [First Answers review item](https://ell.stackexchange.com/review/first-answers/132315) about a (questionable) answer that received four (still pending) rude/abusive flags. That leads to the familiar notice

> Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review carefully

but it's shown on the *Question* tab, rather than where it belongs, the *Answer* tab. I checked the question but it did not have any disputed or declined spam flags.

[image]

Comment: ...Yep, can confirm that I'm also seeing the notice only on the "Question" tab, despite there being several rude/abusive flags on that answer and no such flags on the question.